# Problema ao tipar primeiro parametro do setState do React

Tags: react, typescript, react-native, tipagem, react-hooks

Olá, sou meio novo no mundo do typescript e está acontecendo algo que não consigo explicar o porquê.

Tenho o seguinte state:

```js
const [estaExecutando, mudarExecucao] = useState(false);
```

Passo para o meu componente da seguinte forma:

```
<Contador
   tempo_total={tempoTotal}
   estaExecutando={estaExecutando}
   mudarExecucao={mudarExecucao}
/>
```

Então dentro desse componente tenho a seguinte interface e implementação:

```
interface ContadorProps {
  tempo_total: number;
  estaExecutando: Boolean;
  mudarExecucao: (prev: boolean) => boolean; // Vai receber no prev o estado anterior que no caso seria true ou false e vai retornar também true ou false
}

const Contador: React.FC<ContadorProps> = ({ tempo_total, estaExecutando, mudarExecucao }) => {
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => mudarExecucao((prev: boolean) => !prev)}>
       Play/pause
    </TouchableOpacity>
}
```

Isso me dá o seguinte erro:

> Argument of type '(prev: boolean) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean'.

Já tentei colocar na interface que essa função retorna void.
Também já tentei tirar o boolean do prev

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => mudarExecucao((prev) => !prev)}>
```

Mas ainda sim o mesmo erro.
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `setState` é muito mais do que uma simples função que retorna somente um booleano. Nas variáveis do `useState`, o segundo elemento (`mudarExecucao`) é uma função do tipo `Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>` onde ela recebe um parâmetro booleano, no caso `prev`, e não retorna nada.

De fato, a função `setState` **não retorna nada**, então você definir o tipo :

```
mudarExecucao: (prev: boolean) => boolean;
```

para uma função do tipo `setState` vai fazer o TypeScript lançar esse erro.

### Como resolver isso...

No seu arquivo onde temos o `Contador`, vamos importar o `SetStateAction`:

```js
import React, { SetStateAction } from 'react';

...
```

Agora na interface `ContadorProps`, vamos definir o tipo da função `mudarExecucao` como `React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>`.

Vejamos abaixo:

```js
interface ContadorProps {
  tempo_total: number;
  estaExecutando: Boolean;
  mudarExecucao: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
```

Repare que `React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>` eu passei `boolean`, pois é o tipo do parâmetro `prev`.

Dando uma visão geral de como deveria ficar (mais ou menos) o arquivo do `Contador`:

```js
import React, { SetStateAction } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Text } from 'react-native';

interface ContadorProps {
  tempo_total: number;
  estaExecutando: Boolean;
  mudarExecucao: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Contador: React.FC<ContadorProps> = ({
  tempo_total,
  estaExecutando,
  mudarExecucao
}) => {
  // ...
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => mudarExecucao((prev: boolean) => !prev)}>
        <Text>Play/pause</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Contador;
```

### Sobre o `Dispatch`

É simplesmente definido como `(valor: V) => void`, uma função que recebe um valor e não retorna nada.

### Sobre `SetStateAction`

`SetStateAction<S>` é definido como:

```
S | ((prevState: S) => S)
```

Portanto, o tipo de `Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>` é na verdade:

```
(value: S | ((prevState: S) => S)) => void
```

uma função que obtém uma versão atualizada do *state* **ou** uma função que reproduz a versão atualizada com base na versão anterior do *state* (`(prevState: S) => S`). Em ambos os casos, podemos deduzir que o segundo elemento retornado por `setState` é uma função que podemos chamar para atualizar o estado do componente.

### Resumindo....

`Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>` é o tipo que deve ser declarado para uma função que altera um estado do React (`setState`) e `S` representa o *Generic* do tipo do parâmetro informado.

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, valeu demais! Eu não sabia que precisava de uma tipagem específica para isso. Tem outras funções do React que precisam de tipagem específica também?

Comment: teria que consultar a documentacao para ver o tipo de cada de acao de um hook do React, mas creio que cada uma tem uma tipo especifico para cada acao.