# Property 'todos' is missing in type '{ setTodos: (todos: ITodo[]) => void; key: string; text: string; }' but required in type 'Props'

Tags: react, typescript

Eis os meus erros:

> Property 'todos' is missing in type '{ setTodos: (todos: ITodo[]) =>
> void; key: string; text: string; }' but required in type 'Props'.
>
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ITodo[]'.
>
> Type
> 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<never[]>>' is not assignable to type '(todos:
> ITodo[]) => void'.   Types of parameters 'value' and 'todos' are
> incompatible.
>
> ```
> Type 'ITodo[]' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
>   Type 'ITodo[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
>     Type
> ```

'ITodo' is not assignable to type 'never'.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eis o código:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BsCheck, BsTrashFill} from 'react-icons/bs';

interface ITodo {
  id: string,
  text: string,
  completed: boolean
}

type Props = {
  text: string,
  todos: ITodo[],
  setTodos: (todos: ITodo[]) => void
}

const Todo: React.FC<Props> = ({text, todos, setTodos}) => {
  const deleteHandler = () => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(el => el.id !== todos.id))
  }

  return(
    <div className="todo">
      <li className="todo-item">{text}</li>
      <BsCheck className="check" size={35}/>
      <BsTrashFill onClick={deleteHandler} className="trash" size={35}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Todo;

import React from 'react';
import Todo from './Todo';
interface ITodo {
  id: string,
  text: string,
  completed: boolean
}

type Props = {
  todos: ITodo[],
  setTodos: (todos: ITodo[]) => void
}

const TodoList: React.FC<Props> = ({todos, setTodos}) => {

  return(
    <div className="todo-container">
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todos.map(todo => (
          <Todo setTodos={setTodos} key={todo.id} text={todo.text}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';

function App(){
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="title">
        <h1><span suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">Your name</span> todo list</h1>
      </div>
      <Form setInputText={setInputText} todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} inputText={inputText}/>
      <TodoList setTodos={setTodos} todos={todos}/>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;

import React from 'react';
import { BsPlusSquareFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

type Props = {
  setInputText: (value: string) => void,
  inputText: string,
  todos: string[],
  setTodos: (value: string[] | any) => any
}

const Form: React.FC<Props> = ({ setInputText, todos, setTodos, inputText }) => {
  const getInputText = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  }
  const submitTodoHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([
      ...todos, {text: inputText, completed: false, id:uuidv4()}
    ]);
    setInputText("");
  }
  return(
    <form>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="inputTodo">
          <input value={inputText} type="text" placeholder="Write here your todo" onChange={getInputText}/>
          < BsPlusSquareFill className="plus-sign" onClick={submitTodoHandler} size={40}/>
        </div>
        <select name="todos" id="todos">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="Uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

Como posso resolver estes erros?

Comment: acho que já vi uma pergunta semelhante esses dias, mas é mensagem é bem clara `Type 'ITodo[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'` está tentando usar um tipo onde é esperado `never`, ou seja, "nada" por assim dizer

Comment: Então como é que eu posso mudar o tipo? Porque não posso utilizar o never

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler  [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 1):

Seu código foi um pouco dificil de testar, mas acho que encontrei uma possível solução.

Primeiro, como já havia mencionado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/497527/95771), o tipo para uma funcão `setState` é um `React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>`, onde `S` é o tipo que se recebe por parâmetro na funcão `setState`, algo como:

```
(value: S | ((prevState: S) => S)) => void
```

Nesse caso, para todos os `setTodos` das suas `Props`, deveriamos colocar:

```
type Props = {
  ...
  setTodos: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<ITodo[]>>;
}
```

Não esqueça de importar o `SetStateAction`:

```
import React, { useState, SetStateAction } from 'react';
```

Outro detalhe, no seu componente `TodoList`, você esqueceu de passar o `todos`:

```
<Todo setTodos={setTodos} key={todo.id} text={todo.text}/> <= aqui
```

Pois ele é necessário na *Props* do componente `Todo`:

```
type Props = {
  text: string;
  todos: ITodo[]; // aqui
  setTodos: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<ITodo[]>>;
};
```

Então adicione ele:

```
   ...
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <Todo
            setTodos={setTodos}
            key={todo.id}
            text={todo.text}
            todos={todos}  <= adicionei aqui
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
   ...
```

Agora, nos comentários você mencionou:

> Então como é que eu posso mudar o tipo? Porque não posso utilizar o never

Se você quer mudar o tipo, mude no tipo do estado inicial, ou seja, no `useState`:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[]>([]);
```

Isso é pra resolver o problema do tipo:

> Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<never[]>>' is not assignable to type '(todos: ITodo[]) => void'. Types of parameters 'value' and 'todos' are incompatible.

Pois agora temos um tipo para o estado inicial.

Nos testes que fiz, essas alteracões resolveram os problemas, lembrando que não usei o componente `Form` pois ele não tinha relacão com o problema. Me dê o feedback caso resolva ou não o seu problema.

---

No seu arquivo do `Form`, a tipagem da `Prop` está com tipo errado para `todos` e `setTodos`:

```
type Props = {
  setInputText: (value: string) => void,
  inputText: string,
  todos: string[],                         // aqui
  setTodos: (value: string[] | any) => any // e aqui 
}
```

Faça os ajustes para esse arquivo também, alterando o tipo de `todos` e `setTodos`:

```
type Props = {
  text: string;
  // todos: string[],
  // setTodos: (value: string[] | any) => any
  todos: ITodo[]; 
  setTodos: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<ITodo[]>>;
};
```

Comment: Não resultou. Agora dá-me estes erros: Type 'SetStateAction<ITodo[]>' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'ITodo[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Type 'ITodo' is not assignable to type 'string'. no argumento todos

Comment: Ah sim, esqueci de mencionar, tem uma `Prop` no arquivo do `Form` que está assim `todos: string[],` mude ela para `todos: ITodo[],` Editei a resposta.